Rstudio and "max-connections" when using R >4.4.x on WINDOWS
R > 4.4.x may be started from the command line with the following flag, --max-connections=X
Per CRAN "Changes in R 4.4.0":

New startup option --max-connections to set the maximum number of simultaneous connections for the session.

But how should this flag be set when using R via Rstudio on Windows?
There are many examples of customizing R using configuration files like .Rprofile and .Renviron but my understanding is that all of these configs are read AFTER R has already started.
I was hoping that something like this would work in .Rprofile:
options(max-connections=X)

options(NCONNECTIONS=X)

But variations of that don't seem to work.
Can Rstudio (on Windows) invoke R with max-connections set to a user-defined integer?

I am pretty sure this will require an update to RStudio.  It doesn't call R on the command line, it runs an embedded version of R, so it will have to provide its own mechanism to set the max number of connections.

You may try setting export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R="/usr/local/bin/R --max-connections=X" in bash_profile on *nix while starting Rstudio from a terminal. For more see https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-the-RStudio-Desktop-IDE

This question remains unanswered at posit community as well: https://forum.posit.co/t/launching-r-with-command-line-arguments/187426

I should have been clearer.  I'm using RStudio on Windows.  I've edited the post to reflect this detail.
